# java.lang.AssertionError during TDD session

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, junit, char

I have this method with this signature:

```
public char[] checkDouble(String s) { 
    int[] letters = new int[26]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
        letters[s.charAt(i) - 97]++; 
    } 
    char[] copyLoop = new char[26]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) { 
        if (letters[i] > 1) { 
            char c = (char) (i + 97); 
            copyLoop[i] = c; 
        } 
    } 
    return copyLoop; 
}
```

and my Junit test case:

```
public class DoubleCharTest {

private DoubleChar c;

@Before
public void before() {
    c = new DoubleChar();
}

@Test
public void test1(){
    char [] result = c.checkDouble("wallaby");
    Assert.assertEquals("al", result);

}
```

Why my test doesn't pass and I have this error?

```
expected: 'al' but was:<[C@3d075dc0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a `String`: "al" with a `char[]`.

You'll have to convert `result` to a `String` before invoking `assertEquals`.

For example:

```
Assert.assertEquals("al", String.valueOf(result));
```

Or you could compare them as arrays like so:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals("al".toCharArray(), result);
```

**Update 1:** In response to the comments below, the issue is no longer in the assertion, the issue is in the `checkDouble()` method. You are assigning a `char[26]` to `copyLoop` then walking through the given string and setting a char into that array for each duplicated letter. You then return that array. So, when you pass in "wallaby" the resulting `copyLoop` contains "a", "l" and every other element in `copyLoop` is the default char value: `'\u0000'`. This causes the assertion to fail but these default char values are not visible to you when you print the result so you are tricked into thinking that the result only contains "al" whereas in fact it contains:

```
`a,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,l,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000`.
```

Comment: public void test1(){
  char [] result = c.checkDouble("casa");
  Assert.assertEquals("a", String.valueOf(result));
  
 }
I am sorry but it doesn't work.
Again: expected:<a[]> but was:<a[]>.
I am confused!

Comment: @Clash could you update your question to include the implementation of `checkDouble()`?

Comment: `public char[] checkDouble(String s) {
      int[] letters = new int[26];
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
          letters[s.charAt(i) - 97]++;
      }
      char[] copyLoop = new char[26];
      for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
          if (letters[i] > 1) {
              char c = (char) (i + 97);
              copyLoop[i] = c;            
          }
      }
      return copyLoop;  
     }`

Comment: I have added that implementation to your question. I think the issue here is with that implementation **not** with the assertion. Both of the assertion approaches in my answer are valid. I think the reason your test is still failing is that `checkDouble()` is not returning the answer your test expects it to return.

Comment: can you please try a test complete, code and junit test together, in your environment?
if you put System.out.println it give us the correct result.
it is very strange

Comment: The issue in in the implementation of `checkDouble()` **not** in the form of assertion. The answer still stands: "You'll have to convert result to a String before invoking assertEquals" or "you could compare them as arrays". But, regardless of how you compare them, if the expeted value and actual value are different - which they are because `checkDouble()` is adding unwanted padding - then the assertion will fail.

Comment: @Clash I have now updated the answer with a diagnosis of the issue in `checkDouble()`.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, I understood the motivation. Now my only choice is to modify the code of the algorithm because as you explained I can't test it.